# Is Journey feature of Branch.IO support SPA (in app routing)?

Tags: react-router, single-page-application, branch.io

My web project is based on SPA and I setup a journey for marketing reason. I set a filter that journey is shown for a specific url.

Journey works well as I access the specific url directly in browser (typing in url input). If I access root url first and do in app routing to the specific url, Journey doesn't work.

Is this by design of Journey?

Answer (score 0):

No, The journey should show up if you navigate from your root. This would need more investigation to check your Journeys setup and Branch Web SDK implementation. Please get in touch with Branch Support by sending an email to integrations@branch.io